# Issue when trying to overwrite a closing brace on notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I'm using notepad++, no plugins installed. Whenever I use a character such as (, [, or {, it auto-completes in red. When I reach the end of whatever I'm inputting, I just close it manually so it "overwrites" the auto-completed one.

HOWEVER, it doesn't overwrite the closing brace } if I've hit ENTER during the code. It just duplicates the closing brace so I'm left with }} at the end of whatever I have, so I have to manually delete one of them. Has anyone else experienced this, and do you have a solution? Thank you.

Comment: investigate it and if you think it is a bug put it to the notepad++ developers bugtracker...

Comment: @Patrick Artner thank you, I will. could you point me to where i can find this bugtracker?

Comment: -seems you found it:   https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/14983/issue-when-trying-to-overwrite-a-closing-brace-on-notepad

Comment: @Patrick Artner yes I found this forum after your suggestion. Although if there was a way to report the bug directly to the devs it would be even better...